# a component for every item of a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I'm a few month old in code and a few *days* old only in Vue. So my apologies for the noobish question but I am kinda stuck here.

I'm trying to render a component structure that should roughly look like this :

```
<div id="app">   
 <list-component>
     <item-component></item-component>
     <item-component></item-component>
     <item-component></item-component>
  <list-component>
</div>
```

The entire list is coming from a json that I am getting with axios. So far, so good... The problem is : I need to create a item component for each entry of the list.

Obviously I tried to put a v-for in my item. By doing so, I can duplicate item components as expected. But then I can't find a proper way to render data correctly within the item component template.

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate a better what I am trying to do : https://jsfiddle.net/devnoob/4r3txkvy/

This actual code doesn't do the trick 'cause I don't have a component for each item.

I tried messing around with props and v-bind as mentioned in this thread [VueJS - Component inside of v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950653/vuejs-component-inside-of-v-for)
 but I couldn't find a way to make it work properly.

Thanks !

Comment: the loop works properly in fiddle. are you currently finding a way to, example, showing id? or retrieving each item inside related component?

Comment: Please, in simple terms, explain what your question is. What are you trying to achieve. Your fiddle shows data in a loop ... What are you expecting it to show?

Answer (score 2):

I think what are you asking is, how does each `alarm-item` component receive and display it's own data?

https://jsfiddle.net/zw7ee4sh/1/

The answer is `props`. 
When you need to pass data from a parent to a child, you must do 2 things.

1. Parent: Pass the prop down as a binding
2. Child: Declare the props you expect to receive.

To begin, iterate over your alarms with `v-for`

```
<alarms-item v-for="alarm in myAlarms" :alarm="alarm" :key="alarm.id"></alarms-item>
```

Step 1: This is where you pass `alarm` as a prop to each `alarms-item`

```
:alarm="alarm"
```

Step 2: The `alarms-item` component should declare that it's expecting to receive a prop named `alarm`.

```
Vue.component('alarms-item', {
  template: '#alarms-item-template',
  props:['alarm'],
})
```

Within the `alarms-item` template, the `alarm` object is now in scope, and you can display the `alarm` object however you like. Here, i am iterating through all of the keys/values and printing them.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="alarms-item-template">
    <div> 
      <div v-for="(val,key) in alarm">
        {{ key }} - {{ val }}
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
</script>
```

As a learning experience, try removing `:alarm="alarm"` from the `v-for`. You'll see that nothing gets rendered, because each `alarm-item` component is not receiving an `alarm` prop, even though you are declaring it as a prop. You can do it the other way around too, keep `:alarm="alarm"` and remove `props:['alarm']`, same result, nothing gets rendered.